# Address already used exception while using two jboss 4.2.2 instances in one machine

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-4.2.x

I am using two instances of JBoss 4.2.2 in one machine. I have changed all the port numbers in the second instance. Still its showing one bellow error while starting the second instance.

```
  14:28:58,624 WARN  [ServiceController] Problem starting service jboss.mq:service=InvocationLayer,type=UIL2
       java.net.BindException: Address already in use
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)



 14:29:00,228 ERROR [URLDeploymentScanner] Incomplete Deployment listing:

 --- MBeans waiting for other MBeans ---
 ObjectName: jboss.mq:service=InvocationLayer,type=UIL2
 State: FAILED
 Reason: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
 I Depend On: jboss.mq:service=Invoker

 --- MBEANS THAT ARE THE ROOT CAUSE OF THE PROBLEM ---
 ObjectName: jboss.mq:service=InvocationLayer,type=UIL2
 State: FAILED
 Reason: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
 I Depend On: jboss.mq:service=Invoker
```

But server got started in both the instances. Can any one pls suggest how to rectify this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Double check that both servers are really stopped before you start them again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you still have a port configuration to do (i.e. not use defaults) for the MQ service.

More info:

- [Solving java.net.BindException](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-configuration/solving-javanetbindexception-address-already-in-use-jvm_bind)
- [MQ Address already in use](https://community.jboss.org/thread/64032)
- [Configure ports](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfigurePorts?_sscc=t)

Answer (score 2):

Did you configure jboss mq ports in jbossmq-service.xml ?If not see https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfigurePorts?_sscc=t